# Add a Track shipping button to WooCommerce My acccount Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am trying to add Track shipping button to WooCommerce My account orders that tracks order from the order ID, using the following code in funtions.php file of my child theme.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'my_code_add_myaccount_order_track_button', 10, 2 );

function my_code_add_myaccount_order_track_button( $actions, $order ) {

    // Retrieve tracking link based on order ID (replace this with your logic to get the tracking link)
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $tracking_link = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_tracking_link', true ); // Assuming you store the tracking link in a custom field

    if ( ! empty( $tracking_link ) ) {
        $actions['track'] = array(
            'url'  => $tracking_link,
            'name' => __( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ),
        );
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As WooCommerce is migrating progressively to custom database tables, you should use CRUD methods, but not anymore WordPress post meta functions, especially if [High-Performance Order Storage](https://woo.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/) is enabled.

Assuming that customer orders have a tracking URL registered as custom order metadata, try the following code replacement:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'my_account_my_orders_tracking_button', 10, 2 );
function my_account_my_orders_tracking_button( $actions, $order ) {
    // Get tracking link custom metadata
    $tracking_link = $order->get_meta('_tracking_link'); 

    if ( ! empty( $tracking_link ) ) {
        $actions['track'] = array(
            'url'  => $tracking_link,
            'name' => __( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ),
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

[image]